# Nagios Plugin: Wildcard for nagios-http-json keys

Tags: json, nagios

Looking to use the nagios plugin nagios-http-json https://github.com/drewkerrigan/nagios-http-json to check a json response.

There is an example (I slightly modified):

```
Data for keys ring_members(0).numberToCheck, ring_members(1).numberToCheck, ring_members(2).numberToCheck:
{
    "ring_members": [
        {"numberToCheck": "10"},
        {"numberToCheck": "20"},
        {"numberToCheck": "30"}
    ]
}
```

If I want to check the first element in the response's array I could write:

```
plugins/check_http_json.py .... -w ring_members(0).numberToCheck,@20:
```

To check if ring_members position 0 key numberToChecks value is greater than or equal to 20 and flag a warning if true.

I could repeat `-w ring_members(0).numberToCheck,@20: ring_members(1).numberToCheck,@20: ...` to check all the values.

However is it possible to check each position of ring_members, when the length of ring_members is unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the plugin `check_http_json.py`, and adding a custom check for a "%all" instead of index position:

```
    def gte(self, key, value):
    if '(%all)' in key:
        array_key = key.split('(%all)')[0]
        array_full = self.get(array_key)
        for item in array_full:
            if float(item['numberToCheck']) >= float(value):
                return True
        return False
    return self.exists(key) and float(self.get(key)) >= float(value)
```

Then pass the following, `plugins/check_http_json.py ... -w ring_members(%all),@20:`

@20: is gte -> Greater than or equal to.

This results with checking ring_members(0 - ring_members.length-1).numberToCheck >= 20